# Swapping first and last characters of string results in seg fault

Tags: string, parsing, assembly, x86, cpu-registers

My goal is to swap the first character with the last character of the string `some_str` in `x86-assembly`.

Here is my attempt:

```
; assemble and link with:
; nasm -f elf32 -g test.asm && ld -melf_i386 test.asm.o -o test


section .text
global  _start
extern printf

_start:
    mov eax, some_str

    _loop:
    mov  di, [eax + 4]  ; ptr to end char
    mov  si, [eax]  ; ptr to start char

    mov  dl, [di]      ; DL = end char
    mov  al, [si]      ; AL = start char

    mov  [si], dl      ; start char = end char 
    mov  [di], al      ; end char = char 1 


    mov edx, len
    mov ecx, eax
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    ret

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

section  .data
    some_str     db `abcd`, 0xa
    len     equ $ - some_str
```

For some reason I am oblivious to the lines:

```
    mov  dl, [di]      ; DL = end char
    mov  al, [si]      ; AL = start char
```

Causes the program to result in a segmentation fault.

The expected stdout is:

```
dbca
```

Actual stdout:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
```

Is there something I am missing? How do I correct this code to correctly swap the first and last character of `some_str`.

Comment: 1. Looks like you're loading bytes into `di` and `si`, when you want them to have pointers instead.  2. If you're on 32-bit then you should be using `esi` and `edi` because pointers are 32-bits wide.  3.  Look at the values in the registers using single step in the debugger, surely you'll see some things amiss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be doing something much more complicated than necessary.  After `mov eax, some_str`, we have that `eax` points to one of the bytes that wants to be swapped, and `eax+4` points to the other.  So just load them into two 8-bit registers and then store them back the other way around.

```
mov eax, some_str
mov cl, [eax]
mov dl, [eax + 4]
mov [eax + 4], cl
mov [eax], dl
```

And you're done and can proceed to write out the result.

Note it isn't necessary to load the pointer into `eax` first; you could also do

```
mov cl, [some_str]
mov dl, [some_str + 4]
mov [some_str + 4], cl
mov [some_str], dl
```

If you really wanted to have two different registers to point to the two different bytes: first of all, they need to be 32-bit registers.  Trying to address memory in 32-bit mode using 16-bit registers `si, di` is practically never going to work.  Second, `mov edi, [eax]` would load `edi` with the contents of the memory at location `eax`, which is some bytes of your string, not a pointer.  You'd want simply `mov edi, eax`.  For the second one, you can use `lea` to do the arithmetic of an effective address calculation but keep the resulting pointer instead of doing a load.  So I think the way to turn your code into something in the original (inefficient) spirit, but correct, would be

```
mov edi, eax
lea esi, [eax+4]
mov dl, [edi]
mov al, [esi]
mov [esi], dl
mov [edi], al
```

Comment: Is there any good references you can refer me to to learn `x86-assembly` like books etc? I really appreciate the help, I am really trying to learn.

Comment: @dnsis_445: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info